# Problems with Canon LBP3300 installation

Tags: software-installation, 19.04, canon

My Ubuntu 19.04 recognises Canon LBP3300 immediately when is connected by USB cable, and everything looks fine until I want to print the page. Then I get message that printing is in progress but never prints a single page. Any suggestions how to fix it or how to propertly install printer? Tried everything from here: [How to install LBP Printer driver in Ubuntu 16.04LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805015/how-to-install-lbp-printer-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04lts) but none of these works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got a pretty similar problem with Ubuntu 19.04 can see Canon LBP6030/6040/6018L (as a wireless device) but printing does not happen.
Eventually I got this working:

(1) initial state. Ubuntu sees the printer but drivers could not be found automatically or pick up from the Ubuntu db manually.

(2) once I installed 2 deb packages from the archive downloaded from
https://asia.canon/support/imageCLASS%20LBP6030__%20LBP6030B__%20LBP6030w/model

```
sudo dpkg --install cndrvcups-common_3.90-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk_1.50-1_amd64
# most like some libs would be missed, run this to fix    
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I could pick up the printer from the list [New printer dialaog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOr84.png)
But anyway the printing still does not happen.

(3) found this instruction from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190#A64-bit_Systems
which leads to install the following

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libpopt0:i386
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386 libxml2:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

with such an explanation

> 64-bit Systems
> Canon CAPT Printer Driver for 64-bit architecture include the proprietary closed-source 32-bit executable captfilter (called by pstocapt CUPS filter, used to convert PostScript data to CAPT data stream) which depends on 32-bit libraries libc6 and libpopt0. The libraries are not installed as dependencies.

After the above the printer came to life.
Note that some of the steps may be unnecessary since the instructions looked like voodoo magic with no clear explanation.